# Can an array be posted more than once in php?

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have a html form which has a number of checkboxes, I use these values in php to run a mysql query. I want to use these values from the checkboxes again to run another query, is it possible to $_POST the array of the checkboxes more than once?

Comment: Add your code to your question.  You probably want to use `$_SESSION` to pass these across multiple pages instead of daisychaining $_POST requests

Comment: Whatever is in the `$_POST` array isn't consumed when you use it, but the content is only available after the form has been submitted. If you refresh the page, you have to re-submit the data, or pass it to the next script.

Comment: what is the best way to resubmit the data?

Comment: ...are you changing pages then? Or just running two queries?

Comment: the page refreshes

Comment: just use the array, why would you want to resubmit data that you already have?

Comment: its for another query that is run when a different button is clicked

Comment: without the code we can't really help you.

Comment: @Beck https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Posting an array more than once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478145/posting-an-array-more-than-once)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share the same post array across multiple pages (meaning you redirect or refresh the page between uses) you can either post the array again, or use session variables.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["myCheckboxes"] = $_POST["myCheckboxes"];
?>
```

You can then use the 'myCheckboxes' session variable in the next pages.

Comment: Can you add some code so we get some more information? Note that you always need to start your session (on every page) with session_start(). On your second page you can use the session with $_SESSION['variable']

Comment: when I try to post the array with $_POST I get an Undefined index: message

Comment: I haven't added it yet

Comment: Code has been added